# multiple subquery error "invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, multidimensional-array, nested, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im working on this code but i keep getting invalid identifer for t2.nabp_num

```
 `with t1 as (query1),
   t2 as (query2)
   Select t1.*, t2.device_count, 
   d.* from t1 
   inner join t2 on
   t1.nabp_num = t2.nabp_num and
   t1.dt = t2.dt and
   t1.d_member = t2.d_member
   inner join drug_product d on
   t1.d_product_id = d.product_id

   order by claim_count desc;`
```

i get invalid identifier

Comment: Get rid of the comma after t1 `d.* from t1,` s/b `d.* from t1`  it's like you're doing a cross join and inner join together.  compiler is getting confused so no t2 exists.  Also: you define t2 CTE with 4 fields.  nabp_num isn't one of them (nor is fill_Dt); and you don't alias one of your counts which gets ugly to reference later... Very odd maybe instead of counts like that you should be using a window function?

Comment: We'd need to see the DDL of all table structures included, sample Data,  the query you've tried (Provided) and expected results.   Otherwise we have incomplete information to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already commented, you can't reference something that doesn't exist.

It would certainly help if you posted actual query instead of invalid

```
with t1 as (query1          --> what is "query1"?
     Order by ...
```

---

Anyway: as `NABP_NUM` is referenced here:

```
inner join t2 on t1.nabp_num = t2.nabp_num
```

it means that it has to be part of both `t1` and `t2`. However, as `t2` CTEs result is derived from `t1`, maybe you don't need `t1` at all ...

If you add all columns that are currently missing in either `select` column list or `group by` clause, query would look like this (see comments within code):

```
WITH
   t1
   AS
      (SELECT d_member_id,
              dt,
              device_type,
              claim_id,
              nabp_num,          --> add NABP_NUM
              d_member_hq_id     --> add D_MEMBER_HQ_ID
              d_drug_product_id  --> add D_DRUG_PRODUCT_ID
         FROM some_table         --> which table?
      ),       --> remove ORDER BY, it is useless here
   t2
   AS
      (  SELECT d_member_id,
                dt,
                nabp_num,        --> add NABP_NUM
                d_member_hq_id,  --> add D_MEMBER_HQ_ID
                COUNT (DISTINCT device_type) AS device_count,
                COUNT (DISTINCT claim_ID) AS claim_count
           FROM t1
       GROUP BY d_member_id, dt, nabp_num, d_member_hq_id)   --> add NABP_NUM and D_MEMBER_HQ_ID
  SELECT t1.*, t2.device_count, d.*
    FROM t1
         INNER JOIN t2
            ON     t1.nabp_num = t2.nabp_num
               AND t1.dt = t2.dt
               AND t1.d_member_hq_id = t2.d_member_hq_id
         INNER JOIN vmd_drug_product d
            ON t1.d_drug_product_id = d.d_drug_product_id
ORDER BY t2.claim_count DESC;
```

Even though this shouldn't return any syntax errors any more (presuming columns used here really exist in `some_table`), I can't tell whether this will - or will not - return desired result.